# Why does sending an email message from PowerShell with the Send-MailMessage command using the flag -Port 587 produce an error?

Tags: powershell, email, office365

I am trying to send an email with PowerShell using SMTP, but have not been able to successfully send it. I have enabled security default which I can not disable due to security concerns.

I have enabled SMTP authentication for a specific email address and disabled 2FA on it.

Here are the PowerShell commands I have tried to send emails:

```
Send-MailMessage -To “email” -From “email” -Subject “Hey, Admin” -Body “Some important plain text!” -Credential (Get-Credential) -SmtpServer “smtp.office365.com” -Port 587

Send-MailMessage -Credential (Get-Credential) -SmtpServer smtp.office365.com -Port 587 -UseSsl -From email.com -To email.com -Subject "Hi Admin" -BodyAsHtml “Some important plain text!” -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

The error I am receiving is as follows:

```
Send-MailMessage : Error in processing. The server response was: 5.7.3 STARTTLS is required to send mail
[SG2PR01CA0139.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com]
At line:1 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -To “email” -From “email ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo         : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Answer (score 2):

Some SMTP servers may have been hardened to only accept TLS 1.2 for negotiating STARTTLS. In many cases Windows is configured to send TLS 1.0 by default when `-UseSSL` is specified.

To force `Send-MailMessage` to use TLS 1.2 it is necessary to add a line to the script before executing the `Send-MailMessage`:

Try with:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

### or

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'TLS12'
```

Here's a test you can use for powershell o365 connectivity.

```
# Make Windows negotiate higher TLS version:
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$parameters = @{
    From = 'sender'
    To = 'recipient'
    Subject = 'Email Subject'
    Attachments =  @('C:\files\samplefile1.txt','C:\files\samplefile2.txt')
    BCC = 'bcc@bar.com'
    Body = 'Email body'
    BodyAsHTML = $True
    CC = 'cc@bar.com'
    Credential = Get-Credential
    DeliveryNotificationOption = 'onSuccess'
    Encoding = 'UTF8'
    Port = '587'
    Priority = 'High'
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.office365.com'
    UseSSL = $True
}

# Notice: Splatting requires @ instead of $ in front of variable name
Send-MailMessage @parameters
```

Comment: I have tried forcing to use TLS 1.2, but it doesn't work.

Comment: are you also using the `-usessl` flag? it appears to be required.

Comment: [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'TLS12'
Send-MailMessage -Credential (Get-Credential) -SmtpServer smtp.office365.com -Port 587 -UseSsl -From tracker@email.com -To tracker@email.com -Subject "Hi Admin" -BodyAsHtml “Some important plain text!” -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)

Comment: And I have enabled MFA on this email box and used the app password ( Office365). Thank you for trying to help me. :)

Comment: @TharinduDamith try my edited code

Comment: Your script is working fine. But my issue is not resolved. I think I have to disable security default from Office 365. Thank you for the given support.